# Prove these two functions are in $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove that the equation 
$$u -\Delta u=f$$

with $f \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ admits a solution in $H^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $n=1,3$.

Taking Fourier transforms and resolving, I get:

$$u(x)=\left( \frac {e^{-|y|}}{2}  \ast f \right) (x)$$

when $n=1$ and

$$u(x)=\left( \frac {e^{-|y|}}{4 \pi |y|}  \ast f \right) (x)$$

when $n=3$. Do these functions belong to $H^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)$? And how do I prove it?
(I don’t know if I should use the $H$ definition with approximations or the $W$ definition with weak derivatives)

EDIT: I just realized (don’t know why it took so much) that the problem I had can be solved by using Young inequality. For some reason I kept thinking I needed the derivative of $\frac{e^{-|x|}}{|x|}$ to be in $L^2$

Comment: Use \ast for convolution instead of \star.

Comment: Can you calculate the derivatives directly?

Comment: Yeah, but I fear those would not be in $L^2$, especially for the second case with $n=3$, because you have a division by $|y|$. Of course I would put all the derivatives on the first term

Comment: Actually it would be great if it worked with $W^{2,p}$ with $p \in (1,2)$, because of the work I’ll have to do later.

Comment: If you need $H^s$ regularity I would work purely in Fourier. A function is $H^2$ iff $(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}\in L^2$, use this.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro thanks! Just 2 questions: what do you mean by “work purely in Fourier”? And do you know where can I find a reference for that result?

Comment: Also you meant “a function is in $H^s$ iff...”, right?

Comment: If (for some reason) you really wish to calculate the derivatives, this is also possible. If $u$ is given by $u = K \ast f$, then $\partial_i u = (\partial_i K) \ast f$ and $\partial_{ij} u = (\partial_{ij} K) \ast f$ for all $i,j$, and one just needs to calculate $K$, $\partial_i K$, $\partial_{ij} K$ and apply Young's inequality. Warning: second order distributional derivatives of $K$ are just measures!

Comment: I tried that, indeed! It should be enough for $u$ to be in $H^2$ that its derivatives are in $L^2$ (right?). In dimension 1 it should work, but taking partial derivatives I get a term like $\frac{e^{-|x|} x_j}{|x|^3}$ and this shouldn’t be in $L^2$.

Comment: Maybe I should compute weak derivatives of $K$, but how do i do that? Simply using the $W$ definition of Sobolev space? Also, what do you mean that the second derivative is a measure?

Comment: Actually, I don’t know why I wanted the derivative of $\frac{e^{-|x|}{||x|}$ to be in $L^2$ since I can simply use Young inequality. Using that, there shouldn’t be any problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourier transforming, we see that the equation is equivalent to 
$$
(1+|\xi|^2)\hat{u}(\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi). $$
In particular, 
$$
\|u\|_{H^2}^2=\int_{\mathbb R^n} |\hat{u}(\xi)(1+|\xi|^2)|^2\, d\xi=\int_{\mathbb R^n} |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2\, d\xi, $$
and $\hat{f}\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ by Plancherel's theorem, so  the integral in the right-hand side is finite. Thus, $u\in H^2$.

Comment: I will use this if I can’t find a more direct method. I mean, this is right, but I’ve explicitly calculated the solution, and I would like to have something more “direct”, which uses explicitly the expressions I have found.